# Ionic 4: Change padding on Input fields

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I'm trying to change the padding off input field by changing the css4 variable but I must be doing something wrong because the padding is not changing. I'm still getting use to css4. This is my scss file.

```
app-page {
    --padding-end: 50px;

    ion-input{
        padding: var(--padding-end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ion-input {
    --padding-end: 12px;
}
```

Did what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using SASS? Variable declaration would look like this:

```
app-page {
   $padding-end: 50px;

   ion-input{
      padding: $padding-end;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ionic 4 uses css4 and as far as I know you can use css4 not scss. It’s still being used for mixins and such but that’s another topic.

Comment: Yes so you get css4 and sass in this case.

Comment: When you inspect the element the is var(padding-end) on input-native which I would like to overwrite.

Comment: Don't know why but this does not work. Not even with `!important`